# Recorrer json sin necesidad de parsearlo

Tags: c#, json

No se si la descripción de la pregunta sea la correcta pero tratare de explicarme.
Recibiré un Json en c# y lo mas fácil seria crear una entidad similar al json y parsearla. 
Pero lo que en realidad quiero es leer el json desde el primer atributo junto con valor o poder saber si ese atributo es un arreglo y recorrer cada atributo sucesivamente.

leer el atributo junto con se valor, y, en caso de ser un arreglo poder recorrerlo pero necesito obtener ambos valores, el nombre del atributo y su valor.
Esto, con el fin de no ligar el json a una entidad definida ya que lo que se pretende lograr es poder recorrer un json X (cualquiera) y poder hacer toma de decisiones en caso de que algún atributo sea un arreglo, hacerlo genérica la lectura del json y no ligarla a una entidad.

Espero me halla explicado de la mejor manera. y si no ofrezco una disculpa.

Agradezco de antemano su tiempo y respuesta.

Mil gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te equivocas con la terminología. Si necesitas parsearlo de lo contrario solo es un string y ni siquiera sabes si es un JSON válido o no. Lo que no quieres es deserializarlo en un objeto strongly typed sino recorrer el JSON.

Usando [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) es fácil pasear un JSON usando `JObject.Parse` que te devuelva un `JObject` con los métodos adecuados para poder leerlos manualmente.

Ejemplo:

```
string json = "{\"Hola\":\"Mundo\"}"; //Acá va tu JSON
JObject o = JObject.Parse(json);
var primerAtributo = o.Properties().First().Name; // Hola
```

Comment: tienes razón ya lo estuve revisando con un foreach puedo iterar las propiedades que se encuentran al principio de mi json el problema que tengo ahorita es cuando algunas de las propiedades tiene un arreglo o mas popiedades dentro

Comment: foreach (var item in o.Properties())
                {

Comment: {
 "presupuesto": "1234",
 "nombrecliente": "Alfredo",
 "appaterno": "Villegas",
 "apmaterno": "Machorro",

 "productos": [
  {
   "sku": "36000651",
   "name": "SET DE 32 PZA DADOS C/MATRACA",
   "quantity": "1",
   "precio": "88.99"
  }
 ]
}// No se como obtener las propiedades de productos ya que la variable item del foreach solo me los da como string y al concatenarlo e intentar volver a intentar convertirlo de la siguiente manera me da una excepcion JObject o = JObject.Parse(item.Value);

Comment: Si una de las propiedades es un array entonces castéalo a `JArray`

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu tiempo, si me funciona. tuve que adaptarlo debido a la conversión pero si es como lo buscaba, muchas gracias. ¿Recomiendas cambiar el titulo del tema?